# syslog shows failure to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update . .

Tags: boot, permissions

I am having slow boot times with a particular error which eats up 30+ seconds.

Version:

```
$ uname -v -r
4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017
```

Error:

```
Mar  5 17:24:03 InFlames systemd[1]: Stopped Read required files in advance.
Mar  5 17:24:03 InFlames systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
Mar  5 17:24:31 InFlames gnome-session[1994]: (gnome-software:2129): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Mar  5 17:24:31 InFlames gnome-session[1994]: message repeated 3 times: [ (gnome-software:2129): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered]
```

- How can we start fixing this?
- What is the GDbus?

Comment: PLease clarify: Does this issue occur before login? After login? A few minutes after login? Or only when opening the Ubuntu Software application?

Comment: Before login, there is a purple screen which takes up the entire monitor.